# BOOST MPL Adding two list_c objects results in unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, boost, transform, typedef, boost-mpl

I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/mpl/list_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal_to.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace boost::mpl;

typedef list_c<long,0,2,4,6,8,10> evens;
typedef list_c<long,2,3,5,7,11,13> primes;
typedef list_c<long,2,5,9,13,19,23> sums;

typedef transform< evens, primes, plus<> >::type result;
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( equal< result,sums,equal_to<_1,_2> > ));

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(sums).name() << std::endl << typeid(result).name() << std::endl;
    assert(typeid(sums) == typeid(result));
}
```

It compiles, so the BOOST_MPL_ASSERT holds. However, when running it, the assertion in main function fails. What does it mean? Shouldn't two list_c things (I seem to lack the proper word) containing the same elements define the same type?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

MPL does not make any guarantees about the exact types that result from the the MPL algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

`transform` outputs an unspecified sequence type (of `integral_c<long, n>` elements), not a `list_c`.

One way to convert the result of `transform` into a known type is to use `insert_range` on a `list`:

```
insert_range<list0<>, begin<list0<> >::type, result>::type
```

Unfortunately this doesn't yield a `list`, instead an internal `mpl::l_item` type, so you'd have to do the same operation on both sides:

```
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((is_same<
      insert_range<list0<>, begin<list0<> >::type, result>::type,
      insert_range<list0<>, begin<list0<> >::type, sums>::type>));
```

Equivalently, you could use `reverse_copy` into a front inserter:

```
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((is_same<
      reverse_copy<result, front_inserter<list0<> > >::type,
      reverse_copy<sums, front_inserter<list0<> > >::type
      >));
```

Indeed, because `front_inserter` is implemented in terms of the intrinsic metafunction `push_front`, this yields the same type as `insert_range`.

However, it's easier just to rely on `copy` always yielding the same unspecified sequence type:

```
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((is_same<copy<result>::type, copy<sums>::type>));
```

And since `copy` is a transforming algorithm, it returns the same type as `transform`, so you can just write:

```
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((is_same<result, copy<sums>::type>));

assert(typeid(copy<sums>::type) == typeid(result));
```

Comment: Thank you. Am I unable to convert a list to list_c? I have trouble adding two lists.

Comment: @user1864035 no, `list_c` is just a shorthand for constructing `list`s.

Comment: Well, it seem like I'm not finished yet and I'm afraid what you've said isnt accurate. Changing the code according to your advice, (replacing my assert with yours) causes it not to compile, furthermore assert(typeid(sums::type) == typeid(result)); fails :(. Seems like a need a way to convert the output sequence of transform to list .

Comment: @user1864035 good call, I got a bit confused.  Corrected answer above.